# how to print the proof of termination of a recursive function provided in "decreasing_by"?

Tags: lean

I've been trying to learn lean, and my strategy for figuring out how some things work has been (beyond reading the documentation and such) to figure out a proof, sometimes by trial-and-error in terms of choosing the tactics, and then `#print` it out to see how the tactics resolve into actual terms. I've run into an issue, however, when proving that a recursive function terminates; for example, in this case:

```
def LAMt.occurs_free_in (n : Nat) (t : LAMt) : Prop :=
  match t with
  | R m   => m=n
  | A l r => (occurs_free_in n l) ∨ (occurs_free_in n r)
  | L t'  => occurs_free_in (n+1) t'
termination_by occurs_free_in h t => search_size t
decreasing_by {
  simp_wf
  simp!
  apply Nat.lt_succ_of_le
  case _ =>
  first | apply Nat.le_add_right | apply Nat.le_add_left | {
    apply Nat.le_of_eq
    trivial
  }
}
```

I have a working proof, but I can't see what the explicit form of it is because I don't know if it has a name. How can I print it?

Comment: What happens if you `#print LAMt.occurs_free_in`?